# Can not update existing points on chart in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, charts, point

In my `WinForms C#` program, while increasing and decreasing X axis values using a trackbar I need to update the existing Y axis values that were already drawn on a chart `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` but for some reason for most of the X points the chart still displays both the old and the new Y values. Originally I thought that the following should act properly:

```
    private void UpdatePoint(int aIndex, float aX, float aY)
    {
        DataPoint found = null;
        if (_chart.Series[aIndex].Points.Count > 0 && 
            (found = _chart.Series[aIndex].Points.FindByValue(aX, "X")) != null)
        {
            if (found.YValues[0] != aY)
                found.SetValueXY(aX, aY);
        }
        else
        {
            _chart.Series[aIndex].Points.AddXY(aX, aY);
        }
    }
```

First I thought that I am doing the update not the right way and tried deleting the point and adding a new point with the new Y value but although debugger said there was only one point with one Y value for each X I still see two Y values and it means that the chart is not refreshed properly.   Trying invalidating or refreshing the chart did not help. How can I achieve the proper points update. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to remove the old points first, otherwise they'll still be there.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, as I said in my original post, I tried deleting the points completely and only then added the new point with the new value but the behavior was the same. More over while debugging I can see that for each X value I have only one Y value in the chart so I think that the problem is with the refresh of a chart.

Comment: Looks like you do not find the values. Not knowing them we can't help. Note that testing doubles for equality is error-prone, due to floating-point errors. Also note that you need to have added the x-values as numbers or datetimes..

Answer (score 1):

```
_chart.Series[yourSeriesIndex].Points.Clear();
```

As i get the problem; this partial example should help you to clear the old values which series points you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can offer to you is to delete it and switch over to WPF. Winforms is just a too big pain in the ass